# How to have a list with separate attributes instead of having the whole list under a single attribute

Tags: c#, list, linq, serialization, element

Very Recently I have started working with serialization and I want to serialize some data. This data is basically some information about a set of sub directories .
As of now when I serialize this data of sub Directories it all comes under a single tag , I want to know if its possible to have separate tags for each sub directory.
I am Using LINQ for this Serialization

My Current code ,

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Test\Settings.xml");
                        xmlDoc.Element("Iniatial").Element("InitialAttribute").Add(
                            new XElement("Name", RepositoryName),
                            new XElement("Filespath", fullFilePath),
                               );

                        xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\Users\Anon\AppData\Roaming\Test\Settings.xml");
```

My Current Output is ,

```
<Main>

<folder>
    <Name>M1</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\HomeTest\somefolder\file</Filespath>

   <Name>M2</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\RHomeTest\somefolder\file</Filespath>

   <Name>M3</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\HomeTest\somefolder\file</Filespath>

</folder>

</Main>
```

Required output is ,

```
<Main>

<folder  >
    <Name>M1</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\RepositoryHomeTest\smertereg\opts</Filespath>
</folder  >

<folder  >
    <Name>M2</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\RepositoryHomeTest\sykemelding\opts_2</Filespath>

</folder  >  


<folder  >
    <Name>M3</Name>
    <Filespath>D:\RepositoryHomeTest\sykemelding-2\opts_3</Filespath>


</folder  >
</Main>
```

As shown in the required output I want to seperate these items with an extra element tag

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but then again in this code I just get 1 set of items at a time.
I want multiple items instead as shown in my required output

Comment: You didn't provided enough information to give an answer.  The code posted and xml aren't consistent so it is difficult to give an answer.  There is no main or folder tag in the c# code nor where you are reading the directories.